# read jquery array in php

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

i am trying to retrieve the value of array via post in php script.

```
var data = [];
table.rows({ selected: true }).every(function(index){
    // Get and store row ID
    data.push(this.data()[0]);  //create a 1 dimensional array
});

//send data via ajax    
$.ajax({                                      
      url: '/...../...',                  
      type: 'POST',   
      data: {userid:data},                      
      dataType: 'json',
```

In my PHP script so far I am unable to decode the array. Have tried many ways

```
$myArray = $_REQUEST['userid'];
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    $userid= $value;             //for now just trying to read single item 
}
```

I have tried `print_r($myArray )`; this sucessfully prints array contents to screen.

I am trying to retrieve the values for processing! Kindly point me in the right direction

Comment: what do you want to do with the values?

Comment: `$myArray` but `foreach($arr )`? Are you sure what you do here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get data from php array - AJAX - jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395720/get-data-from-php-array-ajax-jquery)

Comment: Could you show us the result of a var_dump. please

Comment: Here are the results of   'var_dump' :   **array(1) { ["userid"]=> string(21) "assssssss,camo,castor" }** @mondersky

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that PHP would recognise the array that you've called "data" as being an array. Couldn't you turn the data from your table rows into values in a JavaScript object, encode it as a JSON string, then post that to your PHP script and use **`json_decode($_POST["userid"])`** on the PHP end to convert it into a PHP array.

Comment: Ive tried encoding the array before posting. This leads to circular reference error

Comment: Did you add the values into an object, not an array, first?

Answer (score 1):

The object you are posting to PHP isn't in particular a jQuery object. Instead it is an JSON object or rather a JSON string. I guess you can't read that object the way you would read an regular array in PHP.

You might want to try to decode the string with `json_decode()`. With true as an function argument, it will return an php array as suggested in this stackoverflow answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6964549/6710876

```
$phpArray = json_decode($myArray, true);
```

Documentation of `json_decode()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

simply use:

```
echo json_encode($myArray);
```

Comment: Would this statement not simply post back the array to the calling script?

Answer (score 0):

You're `foreach` is looping `$arr`, which doesn't exist. Your array is being set to $myArray, so use that in your for.

```
$myArray = $_REQUEST['userid'];
foreach ($myArray as $value) {
    $userid= $value;             //for now just trying to read single item 
}
```

I believe you should also be able to find your values in `$_POST`

Answer (score 0):

According to your var_dump :

```
array(1) { ["userid"]=> string(21) "assssssss,camo,castor" }
```

and if we assume "assssssss,camo,castor" are 3 different usernames.
You should use this:

```
 $userids=explode(",",$myArray->userid);
    foreach($userids as $userid){
        // use $userid
   }
```