# Read Json with php, some troubles

Tags: php, json

I have tried, checked many previous topics, and i cant find the way.
[Parsing JSON with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964403/parsing-json-with-php)
There is the answer, but im blind; actually, im a medimu PHP programmer, but im new with Json.

Here is my Json:

{"result":"true","disponible":{"aaa":"0.00001362",**"bbb":"0.000392"**,"ccc":"0.00788523","ddd":"0.00004443","eee":"0.0001755","fff":"0.1755",**"ggg":"797.64618376"**}}

My code:

```
$balances = json_encode(get_balances(),true);
print_r($balances);
```

The screen show my Json, so everything is ok here. Now, i want take the bolded values from the json and assign it to PHP variables.

```
$variable1 = $balances["disponible"]["bbb"];
$variable2 = $balances["disponible"]["ggg"];

echo "Valor 1: ".$variable1 ."<br>";
echo "Valor 2: ";$variable2 ;
```

But it dont work. I tried with many combinantions and nothing.
What im doing wrong?

Thanks a lot in advance. Im blocked with this.

Comment: `json_encode` __encodes__ to json. And you need __decode__ from json.

Comment: It's unclear what get_balances() returns in your example, but it seems you need to be using json_decode() to access the data via PHP

Comment: Can't you just use the return of `get_balances()` instead of encoding it to json? Assuming you are receiving the json in another script, you'd want to `json_decode` before using it as an array/object.

Comment: Get_balances returns the data "as is" (json format) from a web server.
So i need decode it before assign variables?

Comment: If `get_balances()` returns json you don't need to encode it. Simply decode the return value and you're good.

Comment: As i explained in the other answer, it do not worked (not at least in the "obvious" way i did)

Answer (score 0):

Replace: `$balances = json_encode(get_balances(),true);` with: `$balances = json_decode(get_balances(),true);` if you are trying to get associative array.

Comment: i got this: "Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in...." I already tried it before i posted here.

Comment: @Pedro Well… that means `get_balances()` **already returns an array.** There's no JSON involved here apparently.

Comment: I just readed in the API documentation that they returns a decoded Json file, not a json itself. Thanks. 2 days lost for not read the documentation.