# get 2 classes from JSON

Tags: php

basically i know how to get a json from PHP, 
now i have to get 2 classes from JSON:Login and References
using this code

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

gives me this result:

```
{\"Login\":{\"username\":\"user\",\"password\":\"pass\"},
\"Reference\":[{\"IdReception\":\"1\",\"OrderNum\":null,\"Visit\":null]}
```

but how can i separate Login and Reference? i need to read all References and just 1 time the Login class in the JSON passed, 

From google i can find only examples with one class in the JSON

Thanks

Comment: is your JSON structure correct?

Comment: what is `$data` is it a string?  You might have to use [stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)

Comment: These aren’t “classes”. And what your actual problem is here, is rather unclear.

Comment: your result is invalid JSON. it needs to be `{
 "Login": {
  "username": "user",
  "password": "pass"
 },
 "Reference": [{
  "IdReception": "1",
  "OrderNum": null,
  "Visit": null
 }]
}`

Comment: validated on line, the result is incorrect, for this symbol:"\", but i send by javascriptserializer in c#

Comment: OK i used stripslashes in my code, the basic problem remains

Comment: Show the COMPLETE string in `$data` not just a piece

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964403/parsing-json-with-php)

Comment: it's the complete string $data: {\"Login\":{\"username\":\"user\",\"password\":\"pass\"},
\"Reference\":[{\"IdReception\":\"1\",\"OrderNum\":null,\"Visit\":null]}

Comment: But that is NOT VALID JSON so it cannot be the complete JSON String